# jQuery Autocomplete not showing results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

I'm looking for a way to make it so when a user starts typing into a input field, it will start to generate results underneath in a drop down.

For instance, like when you start typing into Google or the Facebook search bar.

What is that actually called?

UPDATE:

I have decided to use jQuery AutoComplete.

I have the following

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="auto" name="search" autocomplete="off">
</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function($){
    $('.auto').autocomplete({
     source:'connect.php',
     minLength:1
    });
  });
</script>
```

And connect.php
I KNOW I have to sanitize $term before inputting it into my query.

```
if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
  require "db.php";

  $con = mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$password","$db");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

  $term = $_GET['term'];
  $query = "SELECT `name` FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$term%'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo json_encode($row);
  }
}
```

Now when I use chrome tools to inspect the response, It works completely fine, it brings back the data I wanted in a JSON format.

However, for some reason, it states 'No results found' on the page even though there is?

Comment: Try Google search: JQuery autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

It's called typeahead/autocomplete.

Twitter Bootstrap 2.0 (outdated - not available in 3.0) & jQuery UI have what you require.

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap don't have that anymore.

Comment: Yes you're right, was only for Bootstrap 2.0 - My mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all of the records from database and return them.

Comment: It's for a product search bar. So I'm getting all products with the name like $term. I don't see why that is a problem?

Comment: jQuery UI autocomplete is creating the search inside the array that you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making an ajax request to the server (php script). First you would need an `oninput` event handler for the text box for the search. The php script will return the records you want. Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="searchBox" oninput="searchTheDatabase(this.value)" value="let us search it'>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function searchTheDatabase(searchText)
    {
       $.post( "search.php", { searchText:searchText})
  .done(function( data ) {
    $("#results").html(data);
  });
    }
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//put your connection code here
$searchText = mysql_real_string_escape($_POST['searchText']);
$searchTextLength = strlen($searchText);
$query = "select * from products where";
//I'm not sure how you search for only the first so many characters, but you can use $searchTextLength to help you
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['name'];
}
?>
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you and I will do some more coding. :-) good luck!

Answer (score -2):

It's sometimes a part of the UI for the Browser, where it auto completes your fields for you with past entries. There is a HTML5 element called [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) where you can tie that element into the list attribute for an input field to get the same results

```
<div>Choose a browser from this list:</div>
<input list="browsers" />
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

For this, all you need do is populate datalist's option values with entries from your database. something like this would work ...

```
<?php
    $pdo = new POD('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password', [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8']);
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, value FROM browsers");
    $rows = $sth->execute()->fetchAll();
?>
    <div>Choose a browser from this list:</div>
    <input list="browsers" />
    <datalist id="browsers">
<?  foreach ($rows as $row):    ?>
        <option value="<?=$row['value']?>">
<?  endforeach; ?>
    </datalist>
```